# Query within Query

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables

1. A part table that has the DATETIME (Primary) , serialNumber
2. A Process table of Status while running each serialNumber with
   DATETIME (Primary) , Status

Both have queries that work fine.
Query Table 1 produces the Start and End Time of a selected serialNumber
** START TIME: **

```
SELECT pr08_ser.DateTime, pr08_ser.Part, pr08_ser.Serial, pr08_ser.OldSerial
FROM pr08_ser
WHERE (((pr08_ser.Serial) Like "*" & [Forms]![QueryForm]![Serial] & "*"));
** END TIME: ** 
SELECT pr08_ser.DateTime, pr08_ser.Part, pr08_ser.Serial, pr08_ser.OldSerial
FROM pr08_ser
WHERE (((pr08_ser.OldSerial) Like "*" & [Forms]![QueryForm]![Serial] & "*"));
```

Query Table 2 produces the Process Status with a selectable Between Form Start and End Time.

```
**  TIME & STATUS : ** 
SELECT pr08.DateTime, pr08.Stamps, pr08.Reason, pr08.INCH, pr08.CONT
FROM pr08
WHERE (((pr08.DateTime) Between [Forms]![QueryForm]![txtStart] 
And [Forms]![QueryForm]![txtEnd]));
```

How do I substitute the Table 1 START & END TIME for the pr08.DateTime BETWEEN start & end values?

Answer (score 0):

Join to `pr08_ser` twice, once for the start time and once for the end time. Then modify the between condition to use the datetime from each of those joins.

```
SELECT pr08.DateTime, pr08.Stamps, pr08.Reason, pr08.INCH, pr08.CONT
FROM pr08,
     pr08_ser as start_time,
     pr08_ser as end_time
WHERE (((start_time.Serial) Like "" & [Forms]![QueryForm]![Serial] & ""))
  and (((end_time.OldSerial) Like "" & [Forms]![QueryForm]![Serial] & ""))
  and (((pr08.DateTime) Between start_time.DateTime And end_time.DateTime))
;
```